# How to extract only emails in a ".txt" file of more than 90 million lines

Tags: file, email, data-extraction

I have a **".txt"** file of more than 90 million lines that contains data, which are in this form **"Email:Password"**
Illustration:

```
andrew@yahoo.com:mommy845
john124@gmail.com:mylove1547
lilbabyblue@hotmail.fr:nucktb010
...
...
...
...
```

I would just like to extract **emails** and delete everything else from this file. How should I proceed and which tools can I use to do that?

Comment: This question has given me an idea for the next [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/):  Provide code, that when supplied to a spammer, appears to extract email addresses from purloined data, but in fact notifies authorities of the spammers identifying data.

Comment: It would be easy with `cut` providing that there are no `:` in e-mail addresses.